# Generate folders using txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have a .txt file that contains my courses names and for each line which is a course name I would like to create a folder.

I've used that code but it creates a folder per word.

Can someone please help me ?

*Thanks a lot.*

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ fnID.txt"`) do (
    set "var=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=!var:*:=!"
    echo(!var!
    if not exist !var! mkdir !var!
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: For whatever reason do you number the input file and clumsily remove it afterwards? Otherwise change the if command to quote the variable => `if not exist "!var!" mkdir "!var!"`

Comment: Thank you very much! That's working so good.